# update manager_name based on emp_name,manager_id and emp_id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns EMPID, SAL, EMP_NAME, MANAGER_ID, MANAGER_NAME and manager name is null. So i need to update the manager names by comparing empid and manager_id and get emp_name.

I have created a temp table and wrote merge to update the records. 
Is there any we could do it without creating temp table.??

[Screenshot of records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg7Wj.png)

[image]

Comment: Sample data and output will be helpful

Comment: i have attached the screenshot

Comment: Why do you have the column MANAGER_NAME in your table? It would be better to drop the column and determine the name in the select. Keeping the MANAGER_NAME up to date is nothing you really want to do...

Answer (score 0):

Data creation:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPS (
    EMPID          NUMBER,
    SAL            NUMBER(10, 2),
    EMP_NAME       VARCHAR2(100),
    MANAGER_ID     NUMBER,
    MANAGER_NAME   VARCHAR2(100)
);

INSERT INTO EMPS VALUES (1,1000,'EMP1',3,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPS VALUES (2,2000,'EMP2',3,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPS VALUES (3,3000,'MGR1',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPS VALUES (4,4000,'EMP3',6,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPS VALUES (5,5000,'EMP4',6,NULL);
INSERT INTO EMPS VALUES (6,6000,'MGR2',NULL,NULL);

SELECT * FROM EMPS;
```

[image: Before update]

```
-- Query to update the data -- Alternative 1

UPDATE EMPS EE
SET
    EE.MANAGER_NAME = (
        SELECT
            EM.EMP_NAME
        FROM
            EMPS EM
        WHERE
            EM.EMPID = EE.MANAGER_ID
    );




-- Query to update the data -- Alternative 2

MERGE INTO EMPS EE 
USING 
(
    SELECT
        EEMP.EMPID,
        EMGR.EMP_NAME
    FROM
        EMPS EEMP,
        EMPS EMGR
    WHERE
        EEMP.MANAGER_ID = EMGR.EMPID
)
EEEM ON ( EE.EMPID = EEEM.EMPID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET EE.MANAGER_NAME = EEEM.EMP_NAME;


SELECT * FROM EMPS;
```

[image: After Update]

This is a very simple update.

But yes, Aforementioned solution(Alternative 1) will execute one "select" statement for each row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

This would work in cases:

1. When a manager has more than one reportee.
2. When a manager has exactly one reportee.

```
update emp t3
   set mgr_name = (select qry.mgr_name
                     from (select  empno, mgr, CONNECT_BY_ROOT ENAME mgr_name
                            from emp t2
                           WHERE LEVEL = 2
                         connect by nocycle prior t2.empno = t2.mgr) qry
                    where qry.empno = t3.empno
                      and qry.mgr = t3.mgr)
 where (t3.empno, t3.mgr) IN (select t1.empno, t1.mgr 
                                from emp t1
                               WHERE LEVEL = 2
                             connect by nocycle prior t1.empno = t1.mgr);
```